# how filepicker work on android apps with javascript

Tags: javascript, android, filepicker

I write an app with javascript and convert to .apk for android apps(with phonegap) but I can just select file from my gallery and music list. I googled and find filepickr example that seems good. but I do not know how to use it.what should I do to use filepicker. it make me crazy. I feel I can not solve my problem please help me. :'( :'(
    thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I use this link to solve my problem : http://www.openintents.org/en/node/159
just follow the link and download the .apk file , send it to your mobile and test your app the file manager added to it. hope this be useful for you